# Out-put the result in a LABEL control using powershell

Tags: properties, output, label-control

I am writing a script in PowerShell using GUI, to get the user properties which is shown in bold. i want the output to be in a  LABEL control. i got the following error

*Cannot convert the "(get-Aduser  $Holdaccount -**properties PasswordLastSet, Pass
wordExpired,PasswordNeverExpires)**" value of type "System.Management.Automation.****ScriptBlock" to type "System.Int32"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, I was using +, () in the command line like shown below
$var = + (get-Aduser -filter* -properties x, y,z)